# MVC Binding objects to the model necessary?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, model-binding

I have a drop down in my view, which is not bound to any models.

It just contains the month names.

How can I check its value from my controller?

Is it *necessary* to bind it with the model?

Comment: You don't *need* to bind it to a particular model, but you will need to retrieve details of the POSTed form values in the controller. You can use the FormCollection class for this. By default MVC only posts values that have changed back to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a dropdown like

```
<select name='myDropdown'>
    <option value='Jan'/>
    <option value='Feb'/>
</select>
```

You should be able to grab the value like this in your action

```
public ActionResult MyPostAction(ModelNotContainingDropdown model)
{
    var month = Request.Form["myDropdown"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its only necessary if make sense to you model.
If not, define a name for select element and make the controller know (set a parameter on action post).

Based on the example of kyle(but simply,as mentioned above):

```
public ActionResult MyPostAction(ModelNotContainingDropdown model, string myDropdown)
{
    //do something
}
```